# How are my initial log to the consoles in javascript updated if I am changing the variables after logging to the console?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, oop, javascript-objects

So I understand the reference to memory location concept while creating objects & arrays. So lets say here I create an array (arr) and then point arr1 to it and later on change its value, then arr1 array will also be automatically updated in JS as arr1 is pointing to the same memory location as arr is so we are actually updating the memory location. But what I don't understand is why my initial log to the consoles are getting updated to the new values before the actual assignment?

```
let arr = [5,6,7];
let arr1 = arr;


//initial logs to the console
console.log({arr}); //[5,6,7,8]
console.log({arr1}); //[5,6,7,8]

arr.push(8);

console.log({arr}); //[5,6,7,8]
console.log({arr1}); //[5,6,7,8]


let obj = {
  name: 'shashank',
  age: 28
}

let obj1 = obj;

//initial logs to the console
console.log({obj}); // {name: 'rohit', age: 26}
console.log({obj1}); // {name: 'rohit', age: 26}

obj.age = 26;
obj.name = 'rohit';

console.log({obj}); // {name: 'rohit', age: 26}
console.log({obj1}); // {name: 'rohit', age: 26}
```

Its a conceptual question not trying to debug anything

Comment: It's just the behavior of the console (some) to behave in that way. If you want your console to represent a "true history" of log values then log clones / transformations of the data.